# Tor : Stuck at Connecting to Relay Directory

Tags: windows, windows-7, proxy, tor

I have never ever worked with Tor before.

The company where I work used to allow us access to any site we wish.  However, as of the the beginning of this month, they installed a proxy server to filter which sites can be accessed and which ones can't.

The filter isn't only on URLs, but IPs as well, and even hex IPs won't work.

So after some research, I decided to use Tor.  The first day I installed it, everything went smooth and I was accessing any website I wished. The second day everything stopped. I tried to start Vidalia, but it gets stuck at Connecting to Relay Directory.

What can i do to get this working correctly?

I work on Windows 7 platform.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to your system administrator about bypassing the proxy. If the company has installed a filter, then I would expect them to require a business reason as to why you need access to a specific URL.

Answer (score 0):

On the ToR network setting, under "Network" you have a few options. One is "My ISP blocks my connection to ToR network".

You can then add a different entry relay – there are ways to get a different un-blocked entry or Orion Router, it happens everywhere when countries block, or you can also use a Gmail account to get 3 different ones.